# Can I co-sign a repo for maximum security? In other ways: only update with their signature + mine (auditing protonv pn)

Tags: apt, vpn, repository, deb

According to https://protonvpn.com/support/official-linux-vpn-debian/, to install ProtonVPN on ubuntu, I should just download the .deb, which installs the protonvpn repo:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/protonvpn-stable-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable main
```

then `sudo apt update && sudo apt-get install protonvpn`

The ProtonVPN app is a python one, and it's distributed as source code, so I can audit it directly from source code.

Is there a way to require a second signature, from me, to download the newest proton vpn? This way I could audit the app before updating to a new version.

The ideal for me would not be to have my own repo, which would be dangerous, but to require both their AND my signature. I'd inspect the code from another computer and sign.

Comment: What exactly do you think you'll be signing?

Comment: @muru whatever is distributed through apt. In this case, the source of the app

Comment: But you don't have access to the original to sign it, and you don't want to make a copy on which your signature can be added.